# Why isn't (or is) this site graduating along with the rest of the sites doing so this month?

Tags: discussion, support

This month, there are a lot of sites that are going through the first phase of site graduation (removal of "beta" label, full moderator elections, etc., not including a site design or increased reputation levels which are part of the second phase).

Per [one of the site meta posts](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4054/11936), the criteria the team are using are:

- Have at least 1,000 open questions (as of today, there are [6,268 open questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0))
- Have an upvoted answer on at least 70% of all open questions (as of today, there are [1,407 open questions without an upvoted or accepted answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered), meaning that 77.5% of questions do have one; perhaps it drops below 70% when including questions with accepted answers that have no upvotes)
- Have been in public beta for at least six months (this site has been in public beta for [approaching eight years now](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates))
- Not have any community objections to moving out of beta (none have been raised here on this meta site)

Unlike other sites meeting the criteria, there have been no posts here on this meta site mentioning the possibility of moving out of beta or allowing the community to endorse or object to it.

Why is this site not moving out of beta along with the others? Did this site fail the "upvoted answer on 70%+ of open questions" criterion because more than 7.5% of open questions on the site had accepted answers with no upvotes? Did the SE team decide this site is ineligible for another reason? Or was it objected to by the mod team behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my latest knowledge this site is actually to be graduating soon as well, hopefully on the 16th of December.

At that time we will not receive a new design, only lose the "Beta" designation. After graduation there will be new elections held, however because of the amount of sites that are going to lose their Beta status this week these elections will be staggered across 2022, and some might even fall to 2023.

Sorry that we haven't reached out to the community about us leaving Beta status yet, but we assumed the fun will only start once we're out and we can plan the next steps.

If you believe this site should not leave it's Beta period then please make sure you raise a Meta discussion, and we can potentially have a vote around that.

Comment: I've [started a discussion](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/should-there-be-a-migration-path-for-questions-from-the-travel-site-to-this-site) regarding Travel's longstanding requests to have a migration path implemented from there to here, which have been previously refused by SE due to this site being in beta.