# Should there be a migration path for questions from the Travel site to this site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

A moderator has [confirmed](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/a/432/14478) that this site will be going through the first phase of graduation (removal of "beta" label, full moderator elections, etc.) this month.

There have been [longstanding requests](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4601/11329) to have a migration path implemented on the Travel site from there to here, so users can vote to migrate off-topic expatriate questions that they persistently get, without having to have a moderator do so. Previously, these requests have been refused by Stack Exchange due to a policy that there cannot be migration paths to beta sites.

However, given that this site is leaving beta, this policy will no longer apply.

I've [posted about this on the Travel Meta site](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7189/11329), but wanted to also hear from members of the target community so we can get a complete picture. Should Travel get a migration path from there to here?

Comment: I'm going to write two answers as a way to vote as well. Make sure you upvote your preferred option; do not downvote the other. If you wish to add to the discussion, add a new answer.

Comment: So far there's a clear winner on the Yes side. We can likely accept that as the answer soon

Comment: @SztupY And the site graduation took effect today, and the [Travel side](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7189/11329) is also agreeing

Comment: yes. Added the status-review flag over here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## YES

Travel.SE is a high-quality SE site with clear direction on what's on-topic and off-topic, with questions around long-term / settlement style visas definitely on their off-topic list. We could argue that in case the question itself is otherwise of good quality (e.g. if Travel would be happy with the question if it would be very similar just refer to a case where the traveller is bound by short-term visa restrictions), then we are likely to accept the question and will be well received.

We likely have to make sure what the exact rules would be for Travel.SE mods to check before migrating questions here (my initial idea is as above check if the question is otherwise of good quality - just off-topic because of the long-term stay requirement, but there might be other considerations to do). We will also have to see how we would be able to find and close duplicates more easily as with migrations happening there's the chance we'll get a fair amount of extra questions to which we already have the answer

Answer (score 1):

## No

We should not allow Travel.SE to easily migrate their questions to this site. The mods on Travel.SE are different to the mods here and might not know all of the quirks of how we moderate over here. We would also likely recieve an influx of questions that the mods and high-rep users would not be able to properly assess, and there's the problem of potential higher amount of dups.

We should ask the mods and high-rep users of Travel.SE to let the asker know that their questions is off-topic, but there's another site where they should first check if there's an answer - and if not just re-ask the question manually. This would ease with the problem of duplication as well.

One issue would be questions which already received an answer on Travel.SE, during the re-asking of the question we might lose those answers, as not everyone over there are part of this community to answer the new question.